# Why is my breaker tripping after replacing a light fixture?

Tags: wiring, circuit-breaker, light-fixture, circuit

[image: Fixture Picture]House is circa 1920's; no knob and tube anymore but wiring with a fabric type insulation does exist in the ceilings that have not been opened up for renovation to date.

A new chandelier is being installed in the dining room.The old chandelier worked fine but was pretty dated. One switch on the wall to turn chandelier off and on.

Removed the old chandelier. Here is what I found:

1. 3 blackish(brownish) wires twisted together (Live?) presumably the chandelier live connection
2. 1 neutral (whitish/brownish insulation connected to the chandelier neutral.
3. There was no apparent ground wire in the fixture, however the new chandelier does have a ground wire.
4. Another two wires that looked like neutral (whitish brownish) were hooked up together.No connection to old chandelier.

Breaker turned off. After securely installing the mounting plate into horsehair plaster around the old metal box in the ceiling (round) I proceeded as follows:

1. Connected the new chandelier live wire to the 3 black live wire bunch
2. Connected the new chandelier neutral to the neutral wire that was connected to the lone white neutral to the old chandelier.
3. Left the other white wires (D. above) alone.
4. Connected new chandelier ground to mounting plate "green" nut and then as best as possible to the old metal fixture.
5. Turned on the breaker on (but not the wall switch) and the breaker slammed off (presumably due to a short)
6. Disconnected everything

So now what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are there multiple lamps under control of the same switch?

Comment: The main wrong thing was not remembering/taking a picture of how the old light was connected.

Comment: Harper. No other lamps to same switch.

Comment: crip659- That would not have added anything because the wires on the old fixture were not labelled or marked or differently colored.

Comment: B was probably connected to two of the blacks, one black connected to the old black of the light, and the white of the light to the two whites(neutrals), which you could have seen when taking the old light down and labelled.  You did undo wire nuts/tape when removing?

Comment: I did undo the wire nuts/tape when removing but was careful to sketch that the three blacks were together. I am wondering if there is short in the fixture itself?

Comment: I wouldn't like to just do this without getting some meter measurements first, but that looks similar to the UK system where the mains power is in the ceiling not in the wall. The 3 blacks can be bussed together; one is power in, one power onward to other lights [not on the same switch], the third is the hot to the switch. The two joined whites can be bussed [these are like the first two of the blacks, one power in, the other power onward]. Then the other white is the switch return. Your new lamp's live goes to the single white, the neutral goes to the bussed whites.

Comment: You've proved one black is 'mains hot'. You prove the rest by testing continuity between one of the other blacks & the single white, which should then be switchable from the wall. You don't need [or want] the power on to test this.

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a short circuit on the neutral side of your lamp by wiring this incorrectly.

Assuming you have power coming in and onward somewhere else, plus a switch loop, which would be typical, you want the three blacks nutted together but not to the lamp, you want  one of the whites (the switch one) connected to the lamp's black wire, and the other whites connected together and to the lamp's white wire.

What you need to figure out is which white wire is the switched hot.  How to do that: Connect the black wires together, disconnect the white ones, connect a meter to each white one in turn and measure to ground.  Turn the switch on and off, and see which one gets switched.  Another way: Turn the power off, disconnect all the wires from each other, and measure continuity between the black and white wires coming from each cable.  See which pair is actuated by the light switch.

That is almost certainly the reason for the short circuit but another possible reason is insulation failure in your old wires, where the wires enter the box.  The insulation cracks and the wire touches the box.  However I'd look first at wiring this correctly.

Answer (score 0):

`that's what I thought based on what I read on the forum. However, I did try one other thing.... After disconnecting everything and turning the breaker on (i needed power to the other room) but without turning on the wall switch I checked each wire with my voltage tester. One of the black ones in A. is hot but the other two black ones are not. Is it possible the live and neutral on the new fixture are mislabeled?` –

The hot black comes directly from the breaker. The other two blacks are for switching. One of the other backs is connected to the hot and goes to the switch. Which one I do not know, but you can find out by tracing it to the switch. From switch it comes back to the light and it is a switched hot. In that case you do not connect all blacks together.

Comment: Ruskes, I will  trace to switch as you suggest tomorrow and will report back what I find.

Comment: OK, do that ....

Comment: Here is what I have found: One of the black wires in A is connected to the switch for the fixture...The other black wire seems to be powering a light fixture (3 way) in the rear stairwell (I noticed this last night when I tried to go down the stairwell) and the also a non-switched outlet in the backporch. I don't know what the thought process when someone over the previous 100 years came up with that. I will get the back-stairwell and porch on separate circuits as soon as I can schedule an electrician but that could take a bit of time.  Any pointers on how to proceed in the interim?

Comment: I figured out what happened but not sure why it happened. When I connected up the new fixture and turned on the power the old single pole switch shorted. When I was checking for continuity as Ruskes suggested and removed the old switch it turns out it was dimmer switch DIVA DV600P "Single-Pole Preset Dimmer Incandascent/Halogen" apparently shorted. I replaced with a new regular single pole switch and re-installed the new fixture and turned on the breaker and viola everything is working. Still need an electrician to separate the ccts. **Thank you all** for your helpful pointers!